# Python package import own files, without knowing the package name at compile time

Tags: python, python-2.7, dynamic, python-3.x, import

```
 - app.py
 - Datatypes/
    - string/
       - __init__.py
       - SomeModule.py
```

My python application loads packages dynamically, loading each package within the Datatypes directory, if the string module (**init**.py) wants to import SomeModule.py it must do so using its path from app.py (the file being executed)
eg.

```
import Datatypes.string.SomeModule
```

I would rather have a way to import relative modules, without having to know the name of the package (directory name)
eg.

```
import __self__.SomeModule
```

Is this possible? If so how would I achieve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the files are in the same directory then you can use the normal

```
import module_name
```

If [absolute imports](https://docs.python.org/2.5/whatsnew/pep-328.html) have been turned on, then you can still import relative paths with

```
from . import module_name
```

Comment: import module_name doesnt seem to work, if I call import SomeModule from __init__.py it will give an error

Comment: What about the second explicitly relative form?

Comment: Just tried the second one, works perfectly. Thankyou very much

Answer (score 1):

If you don't know the path, find it using `os.listdir()`.

If you know the path, use `__import__`:

```
>>> math.factorial(10)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'math' is not defined
>>> mod='math'
>>> math=__import__(mod)
>>> math.factorial(10)
3628800
```

Of course, you need to keep a reference either to the module (variable `math` in my example) or to the element in the module you want to use later.

Answer (score 0):

I created a similar structure in a temporary directory:

```
.
./main.py
./package
./package/__init__.py
./package/sub_module.py
```

The `main.py` simply imports all the package's variables into its own namespace and prints the contents of the namespace:

```
from package import *
from pprint import pprint
print(dir())
```

The `package/__init__.py` file runs when the *package* is imported. It uses **relative** module references to specify that the required module can be found in the same directory:

```
from .sub_module import *
```

The `package/sub_module.py` module is imported by the `__init__.py` of the package. It simply sets three variables:

```
x = y = z = 0
```

When the program is run ...

```
airhead:tmp sholden$ python main.py
['__builtins__',
 '__doc__',
 '__file__',
 '__name__',
 '__package__',
 'pprint',
 'sub_package',
 'x',
 'y',
 'z']
```

you can see, the names from `package\sub_module.py` are imported into the main module's namespace via the package namespace.

Because packages can have a recursive structure you can use two dots to represent the package above the containing package, three dots to indicate the package containing that package, and so on. Though if you need more than three dots you might want to consider refactoring :-).

This system was devised and documented in [PEP 328](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/).